# How can you turn off case correction for HTML attributes in vue-cli-service lint?

Tags: vue.js, eslint, lint, vue-cli

When I run `npm run lint` (which calls `"lint": "vue-cli-service lint"` from package.json), I get the following change in an HTML attribute:

```
-      :auth0Login="auth0Login"
+      :auth0login="auth0Login"
```

This breaks the code, and I don't want it to happen. I've tried the following rules to prevent it:

```
      "vue/camelcase": "off",
      "vue/name-property-casing": "off",
      "vue/custom-event-name-casing": "off",
      "vue/component-definition-name-casing": "off",
      "vue/prop-name-casing": "off",
      "vue/component-name-in-template-casing": "off",
```

These don't work, which isn't suprising, since none of them specify HTML attributes. It was just everything I could find that had to do with casing.

I know linting itsn't strictly necessary, and it's starting to feel like it creates more problems than it fixes, but if anyone knows a solution, I'd still like to make this work.

Pastebin of eslintConfig in package.json: https://pastebin.com/h52YxjRd

Comment: If I remove `"plugin:vue/strongly-recommended", it's fixed, so it must be in there somewhere.

Answer (score 8):

This is because of **vue/attribute-hyphenation** rule

### vue/attribute-hyphenation

- Enforce attribute naming style on custom components in template
- This rule is included in all of "plugin:vue/vue3-strongly-recommended", "plugin:vue/strongly-recommended", "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended" and "plugin:vue/recommended"

### Example :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
      <!-- ✓ GOOD -->
      <MyComponent my-prop="prop" />
      <!-- ✗ BAD -->
      <MyComponent myProp="prop" />
</template>
```

You can ignore this features by adding below line in rules

```
rules: {
"vue/attribute-hyphenation": "off"
}
```

Offical DOC : https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/attribute-hyphenation.html

Answer (score 1):

The rule was "vue/attribute-hyphenation" from vue/strongly-recommended.

This fixed it:
`"vue/attribute-hyphenation": "off"`